# Java Scanner Breaks when an unknown thing is input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a program where a scanner is responding to certain things that you type in.
Here is an example of the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
   int i=0;
   String in = inp.nextLine();
   while(i==0){
      if(in.equals("x")){
         System.out.println("> y");
         in = inp.nextLine();
      }
   }
```

Everything works fine, like if I type in x, it says y. However, if I type in z, nothing happens, then if I type in x, nothing happens and it completely breaks. What can I do?

Comment: I'm not so sure about your "everything works fine if I type x". You are in a infinite loop: `i` is never changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `x` to continue working after you put in a value that is not accepted take the `in = inp.nextLine();` call out like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i=0;
    String in = inp.nextLine();
    while(i==0){
        if(in.equals("x")){
            System.out.println("> y");
            //in = inp.nextLine(); remove this
        }
        in = inp.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is what you were looking for.

Also if you do not plan to change `i`, you can simply keep the while loop going by doing this.

```
    while(true){
        //do stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an infinite loop right so your program is stuck there. Since the second time you enter z which is not equal to x so your code flow doesn't go into the if and get stuck in the infinite loop since your i variable doesn't change either.

Answer (score 3):

You have created infinite loop.
When input is z, check for equalitiy fails and loop keeps spining on condition i == 0 which is always true.

Answer (score 1):

Move this line:

```
in = inp.nextLine();
```

outside of the curly braces that it is in.

Also, as others have said you have an infinite loop. One way to fix that is have a sentinel character (like 'q') that it checks for and breaks out if it is detected.

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone said, you're in an infinite loop, and when you type `z` and the equality check fails, you never enter the `if` block again to check for user input, so typing `x` again after `z` won't print anything.

Assuming you want to keep your program as is and continually ask for input, you can just move the:

```
in = inp.nextLine();
```

after the `if` block.

You may want to have some sort of terminating condition though so the program can exit (like you exit the loop when the user types `q` or something along those lines).

Answer (score 1):

When you enter `z`, nothing happens because you did not instruct it to do anything if inpout is not equal to `x`.

Since the `in = inp.nextLine();` is in the if condition, it wont read anything from the keyboard if you do not enter `x`. So move it outside of the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i=0;
    String in = inp.nextLine();
    while(i==0){
    if(in.equals("x")){
        System.out.println("> y");
    }else{
        System.out.println("input != x");
    }
    in = inp.nextLine();
 }
```